# Can't reduce font-size in navbar when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've managed to put together some code that will allow my navbar to shrink when the user scrolls, however I also want the nav links to reduce in font-size but I seem to be missing something, nothing happens no matter how I write my code.

Since I don't want to target each link text individually I've tried to set a class and target the class using getElementsByClassName and using style.fontsize. I also tried to create a CSS class and applying it when scrolling.

Here's my js code:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbarTop").style.padding = "10px 0px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "40%";
    document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link .topItem").addClass('scrollFontSize');
  } else {
 document.getElementById("navbarTop").style.padding = "40px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "50%";
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item ml-auto active">
            <a class="nav-link topItem" href="#">HEM<span class="sr-only"> (Aktiv)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link topItem" href="#">BLOGG</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link topItem" href="#">RESURSER</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link topItem" href="#">KONTAKT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.scrollFontSize {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Any console.error?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName("nav-link .topItem")` is invalid. Firstly because the classnames need to be separated by whitespace only, not including the `.` prefix, and secondly because the argument is not a selector; it's a list of individual classes to find. I'd suggest using `querySelectorAll()` and looping through the results. Alternatively you can simplify this all with jQuery, as you have it tagged

Comment: Can you use jQuery here?

Comment: Probably, I've done so many changes to this code that I lost track of what is jQuery and what is plain js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I stumbled over a solution to my problem. There's a Codepen link to a possible solution in the second post in this thread: 
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/change-font-size-while-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing jQuery syntax with pure JavaScript.
Try to replace the line where you set the scrollFontSize class with this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a.nav-link, a.topItem").forEach(function(childElement){
    childElement.classList.add('scrollFontSize');
});
```

A better solution will be to use jQuery.

Comment: I sure am. Happens when I try several solutions and forget to reset between each. Your suggestion did not work, however I'm going back to research jQuery. Strange I can't find any jQuery examples of this function because I'm learning a lot more from looking at actual code examples....